# conditional ObservableForProperty

Tags: observablecollection, observable, reactiveui

I'm new in WPF trying to use ReactiveUI, 
I want to call 3 different method based on property value changed. 
so

```
public int Number 
{ 
set 
{ 
   number = val; 
   if (_number == 1) Call1() 
      else if (_number == 2) call2() 
      else if (_number == 3) call3() 
} 
}
```

above is working but now I'm trying using ReactiveUI 
so what i did

```
this.ObservableForProperty(x => x._number).Subscribe( => Call1());
```

is there any way to achieve above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you set up your property like this (assuming your class derives from ReactiveObject):

```
 public int Number
    {
        get
        {
            return _number;
        }
        set
        {
            this.RaiseAndSetIfChanged(ref _number, value);
        }
    }
```

Or, you need to get it to fire property changed notifications some other way.

You didn't say if you are observing the property within the class itself or from a different one.  For example, is this all occurring in your ViewModel or in your View watching your ViewModel?

If within the ViewModel with the `Number` property, I would try something along these lines:

```
this.WhenAnyValue(t => t.Number)
            .Subscribe(i =>
                       {
                           if (i == 1)
                           {
                               Call1();
                           }
                           else if (i == 2)
                           {
                               Call2();
                           }
                           else if (i == 3)
                           {
                               Call3();
                           } 
                       }
            );
```

If you were in your View that had a `ViewModel` property holding the ViewModel with the `Number` property I would try:

```
this.ObservableForProperty(t => t.ViewModel.Number,i => i)
            .Subscribe(i =>
                       {
                           if (i == 1)
                           {
                               Call1();
                           }
                           else if (i == 2)
                           {
                               Call2();
                           }
                           else if (i == 3)
                           {
                               Call3();
                           }
                       }
            );
```

Comment: Why do you use ObservableForProperty in the 2nd example?

Comment: @PaulBetts: Some ignorance on my part about whether or not it makes much of a difference to use the various WhenAny / ObservableFor methods.  I originally wanted to use the WhenAny only, but the OP's question specifically asked about ObservableForProperty so I wanted to show it.  Functionally equivalent though, correct?

Comment: They are subtly different, the latter is going to be removed in RxUI 6.0. Always use WhenAny

Answer (score 1):

How about this:

```
this.WhenAnyValue(x => x.Number)
    .Where(x => x == 1)
    .Subscribe(Call1);
```